# Авторизация на сайте через PIN-код Windows Hello

Tags: авторизация, соцсети

Подскажите, пожалуйста, протоколы, материалы или статьи, которые необходимо изучить, чтобы сделать на сайте вход с помощью PIN-кода Windows Hello. Как пример — вход с использованием [OnePass](https://vk.com/faq21414) во ВКонтакте.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API